# Microsoft Outlook [ Content-ID Field in Source Missing ]

Tags: outlook

I noticed that for some attachments in Microsoft Outlook, the source (under `view source`) will include a `content-ID` for attachments. In other cases the `content-ID` will not appear.

A google search does not return many results regarding this issue.

An example Content-ID would be `<image001.png@01DAS603C.29FDASE50>`

When does the outlook source have content-ids for attachments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That all depends on the incoming message. If a received message does not have the content-id header, Outlook will not add it.

If the content-id header is not set, Outlook will match HTML img reference based on the file name.